# When should you make a symbolic link instead of making an alias?

Tags: symlink, alias

It's possible that making a symbolic link is not at all comparable to making an alias. But from what I understand about symbolic links so far, they do the same thing as setting an alias: they define a new command that you can enter into your terminal to execute something with a different name

When should you make an alias and when should you make a symbolic link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big practical difference is:

- aliases are defined in your profile scripts, they are usually specific to you and *they only work in the shell*.
- When an executable is linked to a new name in a bin directory then *it's a system command available to all processes and users*

**Detail**

An alias can include options and arguments, letting you set your preferred default options for a command:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

and has nothing to do with files.

A symbolic link creates an entry in the file system that refers to some other file in the file system:

```
link -s ~/somedirectory/mydoc.txt ~/someotherdirectory
```

will create a link in someotherdirectory to mydoc.txt

However.

If a link is used for an *executable file* then it can give a new name for a command, just as alias can. For instance on my system `ls -l /usr/bin/vi`
says

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     3B 19 Nov  2019 /usr/bin/vi -> vim
```

So now `vi` is an executable command that is identical to `vim`. Similarly, many systems have both `python2` & `python3` installed, and then `python` will be symlink to one of them.

Comment: Thank you! I've never thought about this before, but what significance does making a symbolic link to a non-executable have? In terms of your example, what purpose would a link to `mydoc.txt` in `someotherdirectory` serve?

Comment: @JamesRonald It would useful if there was a script or an application that was set to write to a file that's in a certain directory. For example, there can be a script with many lines that write to `/new_data/chemistry/experiments/type_1` but if the file is moved elsewhere such as `/new_data/chemistry_1/experiments/type_1`, and one doesn't want to alter the script, then one can create a symbolic link in the old directory that points to the file in the new directory.

Comment: @JamesRonald Debian-based Linux systems also use symlinks extensively for the ["alternatives" mechanism](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).

Comment: @NasirRiley That is crazy useful, thanks so much!